# Not earning reputation even after logging out and back

Tags: support

So, I have an answer to this question, [Teleporting certain people](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169499/teleporting-certain-people/169512#169512) which has been accepted, and upvoted once, yet I still haven't earned any reputation on it. I know for a fact that I haven't exceeded the 200 reputation daily limit, the highest I've ever gotten in one day is 149, but even then, I would still get reputation from the accepted answer. I'm pretty confused as to what's going on here, does anyone know what's happening, or had this happen to them? All help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This post is marked as "community wiki", which means that people with lower reputation can edit it freely, but that no one (even the original author) gets any reputation from upvotes or accepted answers on it.

Looking at the history, it appears that you marked it as community wiki when first answering, by using the checkbox at the bottom right of the answer space.

Comment: Ahh, I see now, thanks!